# how to check user is logged in or not in flutter by php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, flutter, dart

I'm new in flutter and programming. I work on a flutter template (github.com/mitesh77/Best-Flutter-UI-Templates) and added a splash screen to it. now I want to check if user is not logged in, the splash screen will not load and user see login page. I tried this (flutter-examples.com/flutter-online-user-registration-using-php-mysql-server) in new project and worked fine for me.
but how to add it to below code.

Code:

```
void main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(<DeviceOrientation>[DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown])
          .then((_) => runApp(MyApp()));
}


/* This is First Screen */
class FirstRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return new SplashScreen(
        seconds: 5,
        navigateAfterSeconds: new AfterSplash(),
        title: new Text('Hello',
          style: new TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
              fontFamily: 'IranYekan',
              fontSize: 30.0
          ),),
        image: new Image.asset('assets/images/splashImage.png'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        styleTextUnderTheLoader: new TextStyle(),
        photoSize: 110.0,
        onClick: ()=>print("Flutter Egypt"),
        loaderColor: Colors.blue
    );
  }
}

class AfterSplash extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('First Route'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Open route'),
          onPressed: () {
            // Navigate to second route when tapped.
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NavigationHomeScreen()),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
      statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
      statusBarBrightness: Platform.isAndroid ? Brightness.dark : Brightness.light,
      systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.white,
      systemNavigationBarDividerColor: Colors.grey,
      systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
    ));
    return MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: [
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: [
        Locale("fa", "IR"), // OR Locale('ar', 'AE') OR Other RTL locales
      ],
      locale: Locale("fa", "IR") // OR Locale('ar', 'AE') OR Other RTL locales
      ,title: 'Flutter UI',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        textTheme: AppTheme.textTheme,
        platform: TargetPlatform.iOS,
      ),

        home: FirstRoute(),
        );
  }
}

class HexColor extends Color {
  HexColor(final String hexColor) : super(_getColorFromHex(hexColor));

  static int _getColorFromHex(String hexColor) {
    hexColor = hexColor.toUpperCase().replaceAll('#', '');
    if (hexColor.length == 6) {
      hexColor = 'FF' + hexColor;
    }
    return int.parse(hexColor, radix: 16);
  }
}
```

Comment: When you are login you need to set a sharedprefrence to save the login @alireza haji hosseini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am gonna show you what i did in my projects,
First you need to install [Sharedprefrence](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) then create file in lib folder  create folder named Utils you can give any name you want and create a file sharedpreference.dart inside Utils folder
`lib\Utils\`

sharedpreference.dart in this file add this line,ps:you can use this files to add more data like,if the api returns userid kind of stuff you can specify here and can access the data across all your screen with sharedprefrence

```
class SharedPrefrence {
     Future<bool> setLoggedIn(bool status) async {
            final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
            return prefs.setBool("logged_in", status);
          }
        
          Future<bool> getLogedIn() async {
            final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
            return prefs.getBool("logged_in") ?? false;
          }
        Future<bool> setUserId(String userId) async {
          final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
          return prefs.setString("user_id", userId);
       }
    
      Future<String> getUserId() async {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        return prefs.getString("user_id") ?? '';
      }
}
```

Login page

This is sample login function where i have used the preference

```
void AppLogin(String username, String password) async {

    var response = await http.post(Urls.LOGIN,
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        body: json.encode({
          "User_Name": username,
          "Password": password,
        }));

    Map<String, dynamic> value = json.decode(response.body);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      dialog.dismissProgressDialog(context);
      try {
        Map<String, dynamic> value = json.decode(response.body);
        SharedPrefrence().setLoggedIn(true);
        SharedPrefrence().setUserId(value['_id'].toString());

        Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DashboardScreen()),
            ModalRoute.withName("/login"));
      } catch (e) {
        e.toString();
      }
    }  else {
      dialog.dismissProgressDialog(context);
      var message = value['message'];
      CustomDialogs().showErrorAlert(context, message);
    }
  }
```

in your splash screen add this function,and call the function startTime in initState function,in this your splash screen will show 3 seconds then it will call the   navigationPage where it will check the the sharedprefrence for login status if the user is logged in or not if not it will show the login and if it is loged in it will redirect to dahsboard screen

```
 startTime() async {
    var _duration = new Duration(seconds: 3);
    return new Timer(_duration, navigationPage);
  }

  void navigationPage() {


    Future loginstatus = SharedPrefrence().getLogedIn();
    loginstatus.then((data) {
      if (data == true) {
        Navigator.pop(context, true);
        Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DashboardScreen()),
            ModalRoute.withName("/login"));
      } else {
        Navigator.pop(context, true);
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => LoginScreen(),
          ),
        );
      }
    });
  }
```